# Why doesn't node recognize this imported function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I define this function a file like this, and immediately export it.

```
const watchMongo = () => {
        console.log("foo")
    };

module.exports = { watchMongo };
```

Then I import it and run it the main app, as shown here.

```
const watchMongo = require('./controllers/path');

watchMongo();
```

However, I get this error when ran. "watchMongo is not a function".
When I console log 'watchMongo' instead of running it, I'm told "{ watchMongo: [Function: watchMongo] }"

So Node sees and recognizes the function? Until the function needs to be ran? What??

Comment: what does `const {watchMongo} = require('./controllers/path');` do? You're exporting an object with a `watchMongo` property, therefore the way you import it, `watchMongo` will be ... unsurprisingly, an object with a `watchMongo` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one of 2 things. You are defining `watchMongo` as a named export. You can either do:

```
const { watchMongo } = require('./controllers/path');
```

or on your declaration file export like:

```
module.exports = watchMongo;
```

Comment: ...thank you. Yeah. Didn't realize I was exporting my function as an object .

Comment: If you could mark is as answered that would be great!